# Commerce: Diffrent text to add to cart button in product list and in product page

Tags: commerce

i try to modify the add to cart button text in commerce so i can have diffrent text in product list and diffrent text in product page.

Is it possible to do this with form_alter?

I tried to use something like node type but no success.

```
function custom_addtocart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if ((substr($form_id, 0, 30) == 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form') && $node->type == 'product_display') {
    $form['submit']['#value'] = t('Buy');
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to change text of 'Add to cart' button, you should check add to cart form with it's number.

So apply code like:

```
if(strpos($form_id, 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_') === 0 && $node->type == 'product_display'){
   $form['submit']['#value'] = t('Buy');
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hello again! I have to notice that the text switches back to default when i hit the button and AJAX reloads form.

I tried with form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter as Scott suggested but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use $node->type if you add this first

```
$node = menu_get_object();
```

Remember to check if $node is NULL and $node->type is set.

Also if you're wanting to use the "add to cart" hook_FORM_ID_alter() then the function name needs to be something like

```
custom_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter()
```

Comment: Thank you Scott!

I missed that. 

But does not work as i thought... it changes the text in product list also.
I think i have to find another way to distinct the 2 cases and not by content type.

Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe you could try distinguishing via one of the properties in $form_state['context']
e.g. http://i.imgur.com/ipy7YvN.png